# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 1

Tags: java

when i execute method of DAO class error like  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address.cityID=6 OR estate.rate between(2.0 and 100000.0)' at line 1 "

SQl Query is:

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from estate inner join address on estate.addID=address.addID where estate.estateTypeID=? and estate.purpose=? and estate.BHK=? address.cityID=? OR estate.rate between(? and ?)");
ps.setInt(1,vo.getEstateTypeID());
ps.setString(2,vo.getPurpose());
ps.setInt(3, vo.getBHK());
ps.setInt(4, vo.getCityID());
ps.setDouble(5, vo.getMIN());
ps.setDouble(6,vo.getMAX());

ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: rewrite the query to cover multiple lines, then you'll see more clearly where the problem is.  it would also be useful to see the query that is being sent to the server, not only the recipe you are sing to construct it.

Comment: Very low quality question: please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is possible that a field such as `vo.getPurpose` has a single quote in it (e.g. purpose = `This is Varsha's purpose`), thus breaking your concatenated string. Rather, parameterize the bound variables. Also, `AND` has precedence over `OR` so no need for all those parenthesis in the `WHERE`

Comment: you should be using parameterised queries, not just string concatenation.

Comment: I replace query by prepared statement still error like to use near 'address.cityID=6 OR estate.rate between(2.0 and 100000.0)'    : ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from estate inner join address on estate.addID=address.addID where estate.estateTypeID=? and estate.purpose=? and estate.BHK=? address.cityID=? OR estate.rate between(? and ?)");
   ps.setInt(1,vo.getEstateTypeID());
   ps.setString(2,vo.getPurpose());
   ps.setInt(3, vo.getBHK());
   ps.setInt(4, vo.getCityID());
   ps.setDouble(5, vo.getMIN());
   ps.setDouble(6,vo.getMAX());
   
   ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And" is missing between estate.BHK=? address.cityID=?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses around your between values. MySQL do not support those.

```
select * from estate inner join address on estate.addID=address.addID where 
estate.estateTypeID=? and estate.purpose=? and estate.BHK=? and address.cityID=? 
and estate.rate between ? and ?
```

Comment: @Varsha Can you show me the query as you have it as well as the error log?

Comment: change your `or` into an `and` and try again. Look at my updated query.

Comment: i tried that also but still same error: my updated query is: select * from estate inner join address on estate.addID=address.addID where estate.estateTypeID=? and estate.purpose=? and estate.BHK=? address.cityID=? and estate.rate between ? and ?